# how is this lambda function retrieving its x value?

Tags: python

I don't understand how this lambda function knows x is equal to 1?

```
def one(f = None): return 1 if not f else f(1)
def two(f = None): return 2 if not f else f(2)
def plus(y): return lambda x: x+y

one(plus(two()))
3
```

I know that the inner function two() returns 2 because f is defaulted to None. Thus y= 2. But how does the lambda function know to look to the outmost function for the x value?

Comment: `x` is a parameter of the lambda function: `lambda x:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plus` returns a (lambda) function. That function is passed to `one`. Within the scope of `one`, it is called `f`.

Then `f` (which is actually the lambda from returned from `plus`) is called in `f(1)`.

---

In other words, the code `one(plus(two()))` does this:

```
number2 = two()
lambda_function = plus(number2)
result = one(lambda_function)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at `one()` it passes "1" into a function which you pass in the arguments (if a function is passed. otherwise 1 is returned). Thus, it evaluates to `f(1)` (see in the else of one). The function you pass to `one()` is `lambda x: x + 2` (since `y=2`). Thus, this evaluates to `lambda 1: 1 + 2`

If you call `one(lambda x: 50)`, it returns `50`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's run through the steps first:

1. `one` gets a value, `f`, as `plus(two())`.
2. `plus` gets a value as `two`, `two` is gonna be `2` since no `f`.
3. Okay, so since `one` gets the value of that, it gonna condition and see that it shouldn't return `1`, so does `f(1)` the `f` is the unfinished `lambda` process, the `lambda` needs one parameter more to add up, so it got `1`, so `2 + 1` is `3`.

That is the whole process really.